# Static IP Addresses

Tags: networking

I have mototrbo radio software (server) running on a PC with internet access. I need to install a client on another PC in a different town, and have this PC looking at the information on the other one.

I have been told I need a fixed IP address at the server end.

Is this true and if so is there any way to do this without having a fixed IP line installed seperately.

Apologies for my lack of knowledge....

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can a computer with dynamic IP work as a webserver?](http://superuser.com/questions/20580/how-can-a-computer-with-dynamic-ip-work-as-a-webserver), also see [Running a home mail server using dynamic dns](http://superuser.com/questions/253230/running-a-home-mail-server-using-dynamic-dns)

Answer (score 2):

Is the server behind a router?  Also you will need to find out what ports the software uses.  Look for port forwarding on the software support site.  You probably dont need a fixed IP, but you would need to set up a dynamic dns name to assign to the server's router.  No-ip.org will allow you to register for a dynamic dns name.  You may want to hire a friend or relative with some basic networking knowledge to set this up for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about mototrbo radio software. But I know about puting a server on internet.

When you have a server on internet, you need to have a way to find it. An static IP address is one of the ways, however for small applications is better having a *domain name* because an static IP will cost you money and maybe your ISP have to change the actual internet configuration on the router.

If your internet connection uses dynamic IP addresses (addresses that change periodically) then you can get a domain name on http://www.no-ip.org and use that name to connect from the remote site. They have free domain names and also prepaid plans.

On the router that connects the server to Internet you have to configure a port-forwarding because each server on internet have one or more **ports** (imagine they are doors) open.

Web servers usually open port 80 (http) and email servers use some (25 and 110, for example). The port is the conduit to let pass only the kind of traffic that the server knows to manage.

Supposing your server uses port 1080, you will need to enable the port forwarding of port 1080 from internet to your server and it will let your server be accesible from internet. Combine this with the domain name and you have it.